# How can i convince my workmates that we need natural light in the room

Tags: colleagues, stress, mental-health

We have the IT room (5mx4m) where 6 people work inside it.

This room used to be a conference room, so not much time was spent there back in those days, so no complain until then.
The problem is that now we work there, it has 3 windows but only one of them - the smaller one - is actually a window; the other two have some planks on them because of the noise coming from the street. 
I feel quite 'locked' in this room, and i get stressed not seeing daylight most of the days.

I get angry with the fact that the team spends around 10h/day inside this unhealthy environment where there is almost no natural light and nobody says nothing. I noticed that my allergies got a lot better when i took some days off last month.
I tried to talk with our manager about this issue, but he seems to be okay and actually likes to work in the dark.

Am i wrong about these thoughts? The team and company are great, but with this happening i've been thinking about leaving the job.

Comment: So you think natural light from one window will fix your allergies?

Comment: @Frisbee - Sunlight is a good disinfectant and more of it could cut down on molds.

Comment: The question here is probably whether the street noise would be more disturbing to your colleagues than the lack of natural light is to you.  I would find it so myself, but people differ.

Comment: As a compromise, there are light bulbs that give off the full spectrum.

Comment: Allergies are more likely to be tied to ventilation than sunlight.  You should be able to get action on that even if you don't get more sunlight in the room.

Comment: @Frisbee no, but the fact that i feel better about them when i'm not here tells me that something is related.

Comment: I took a few days off and felt better does not show causality.

Comment: @Frisbee just an observation, happens every time. May be just coincidence.

Comment: @william.wd if you can get a doctor's note backing you up, you'll have a better stance at least in the US anyway. I am not as familiar with this, but maybe this problem could be handled by OSHA if going with the mold angle.

Comment: @jcmack didn't want to do something so drastic. Anyway, someone saw this topic and now we started a conversation about our environment. Thank you all

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the boards on the windows can be removed and something that is easier to take on and off is an option, ask if you can get some light for a few hours a day. I prefer working in the dark, but my dog likes to look out the window occasionally to make sure there are no squirrels in the yard, we compromise.

You can always go somewhere for breaks and lunch where there is sunlight.

What is it about your team that you don't feel you can ask for a simple request?

Comment: A co-worker and I have just talked to the manager about this, but no success. Any person that enters our room for the first time says things like: "Wow, this room has no light!" or "How can 6 people work all day in here?".
When i have the chance i take a break outside but coming back is frustrating.

Comment: Are you sure you're specifying to the manager that you want a solution that only allows light in a few hours a day. If I had the option for a dark office, I'd oppose anything that was going to bring in light all day long if I could avoid it.

Comment: Apparently many people prefer a darker office, interesting that i'm reading these opinion. Turns out I started bringing my own laptop and i work now on the other room until we can agree on something inside there. Feeling better. Thank you

Comment: Good luck with getting this resolved. I think some accommodations can be made to at least make it tolerable some of the time. I've been in many offices where I would have loved to take a few hours of the day and go work somewhere else.

Answer (score 2):

Some people may prefer artificial light.

I would say that I do.  Maybe sunlight offers some better benefits (Vitamin D), in addition to some drawbacks (increased risk of cataracts).  Maybe I'm just weird and afflicted by some incorrect idea that I got into my head many years ago.  However, regardless of the reasons, I do feel more comfortable with many types of internal artificial light than sunlight.

> I get angry with the fact that the team spends around 10h/day inside this unhealthy environment where there is almost no natural light and nobody says nothing.

Are you angry at the situation, or the people?  If the people, why?  They may have successfully created the perfect environment that they prefer.  You didn't mention discussing this with anybody other than the manager.  Why be mad at them?  Just because they don't say anything?  It doesn't sound like you're saying anything, either, except for a comment made to the manager.  (And, unless your comment made to the manager was public, they might not know you did that.  Likewise, you might not know who, among them, may have also done that.)

You could try gathering supportive information and sharing, such as benefits of what you'd like to see happen.  Sharing those details might result in you gaining a few supporters who end up agreeing with what you'd like to see.  You may also turn off some other people, though they shouldn't have much of a legitimate basis to get mad if you're just acting positively (this is what I want) rather than attacking whatever displeases you.

As [RichardU's comment](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/63479/how-can-i-convince-my-workmates-that-we-need-natural-light-in-the-room#comment-171458) indicates, some artificial light bults market giving off a type of light that is more similar to natural sunlight.  Maybe those will be good for you.  If you prefer something different than the group, maybe you can cubicle off a section/area so you can spend more time basking in the type of light you prefer.

I remember when a group was expressing pleasure at the large consensus that other people in the group wanted to turn off much lighting in the room, working in the dark (except for computer monitors).  I was disappointed, because I did want some more (artificial) light.  Still, I had to decide whether this aspect of the environment was important enough for me to care.  Personally, I valued other aspects of the job so much, that I just put up with it.  You, on the other hand, seem to care more about this issue.  So maybe the total experience of working at this place isn't as good of a match for you.  That's something you may need to decide.

Comment: Sorry, i didn't express myself very well about talking to other people. And yes, 3 colleagues do agree with me. It's not that i get angry to people, i just feel irritated when i enter the room and see that my ideas were somehow more creative while outside. Feels like i'm inside a box.
**I do like** to be in the dark, but **sometimes** (not 5 days a week, 10 hours a day).